# Why FAB to Toolbar is not working properly?

Tags: toolbar, materialize, floating-action-button

https://youtu.be/4071R5ONUHE

Please see this video.

https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html

I want FAB to Toolbar. Just like the documentation. But when I am using the code, it is behaving like the video. With scroll it is going to collapse. No button is showing on toolbar. Just a Edit button.

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">mode_edit</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"><i class="material-icons">insert_chart</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating yellow darken-1"><i class="material-icons">format_quote</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green"><i class="material-icons">publish</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"><i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton({
                direction: 'left',
                toolbarEnabled: true,
                hoverEnabled: false
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, Instead of displaying individual button options, you can transition your FAB into a toolbar on click. Just add the **toolbar** class to the FAB.

Change this:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
```

To:

```
<div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar">
```